# Значение переменной в название кнопки

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте.
У меня есть кнопка:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/ThemeButtonHead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:minWidth="90dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorHeadTextButton"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы кнопка была подписана не Button, а чтобы название бралось из переменной, которая прописана в классе.
Я не могу сообразить как подобное реализовать. 
может так:

```
int perm = 1020; 
Button buttonHead;
buttonHead = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
buttonHead.setText(+ perm);
```

Comment: Вы, наверное, хотите, чтобы значение в Button автоматически изменялось при изменении значения переменной? Или все же просто установить текст в кнопку?

Comment: buttonHead.setText(""+ perm);

Comment: Читайте документацию хоть чуть-чуть. Вы хотите изменить текст, который в кнопке, или что? Текст - тогда просто `buttonHead.setText(String.valueOf(perm));`

Answer (score 1):

Верно делали. Осталось лишь конвертировать int в Sting

```
buttonHead.setText(Integer.toString(perm));
```